# Java 8 DateTimeFormatter rejects correct ISO 8601 date/time with offset

Tags: java, date, time, iso8601

I use format string for DateTimeFormatter:
uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX

which must support all possible formats of timezone offset, including:
Z, 00, 00:00, 0000

According to official DateTimeFormatter documentation, 'X' qualifier must match to offset in these formats:

*X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;*

but in fact, it doesn't

**input string**: "2014-01-01T00:30:00+00:00"

**result**:
*java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2014-01-01T00:30:00+00:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 22*

**input string**: "2014-01-01T00:30:00Z"

**result**: *correct*

the code:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
OffsetDateTime parsed = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeAsString, formatter);
```

JDK 1.8.0_192 (Oracle, not OpenJDK)

Comment: Have you read that the count of X’ matters? There is a difference between what `XXX`, `XX` and `X` accepts.

Comment: xxx doesnt work with Z either

Answer (score 8):

This is a little bit complicated. [As jvdmr says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54536477/5772882), the count of Xs matters. `XXXXX` will recognize `-08:30:15`, but not `-083015`. `XXXX` will recognize the latter, but not the former.

To take all possible example formats into account, we need to specify different possibilities. This can be done within the format pattern string using square brackets. These enclose optional parts. A little experimentation showed that the following pattern covers all examples:

> `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXXXX][XXXX][X]`

Let’s try it out:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXXXX][XXXX][X]");
    for (String dts : new String[] {
            "2014-01-01T00:30:00-08:30:15", "2014-01-01T00:30:00-083015",
            "2014-01-01T00:30:00-08:30", "2014-01-01T00:30:00-0830",
            "2014-01-01T00:30:00-08", "2014-01-01T00:30:00Z",
    }) {
        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(dts, formatter));
    }
```

Output from this snippet is:

> ```
> 2014-01-01T00:30-08:30:15
> 2014-01-01T00:30-08:30:15
> 2014-01-01T00:30-08:30
> 2014-01-01T00:30-08:30
> 2014-01-01T00:30-08:00
> 2014-01-01T00:30Z
> ```

**Edit**

[VelNaga suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54536560/5772882) not to hardcode ISO date-time formats. Since writing format pattern strings is error-prone, this can be a good idea. For example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .appendPattern("[XXXXX][XXXX][X]")
            .toFormatter();
```

Output using this formatter is the same as with using the one above. It’s wordier, but we could easily end up thinking that it’s worth it since it is less error-prone and may be clearer and easier to read.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) *(emphasis mine)*:

> **Offset X and x:** This formats the offset *based on the number of pattern letters.* One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as '+0130'. Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'. *Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'.* Four letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, without a colon, such as '+013015'. Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as '+01:30:15'. Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException. Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.

This also works in reverse for parsing dates. You want to parse both with and without colons, which means you'll have to use optional sections as no single pattern supports this. Try this pattern: `"uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][XXXX]"`

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcode any ISO date format. DateFormatter already has a static method for ISO date format conversion. Use the below code,

> DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;
>
> OffsetDateTime parsed = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeAsString,
>   formatter);

It will work for sure. Please find this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) for more formatter options.

Comment: True...we should include a pattern. But i see Ole V.V already shared the answer. you can use Ole V.V. answer.

Comment: I cannot use static method, because format coming from outside of Java code as parameter (config file or server.properties)

Comment: @jvdmr One hint though, a mixture of extended and basic ISO-variants as shown in `2014-01-01T00:30:00+0000` is not valid ISO according to the paper of ISO-standard but of course you are free to parse it with a hackish (and ugly) workaround like `"uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][XXXX]"`